# Capping temperature - 2D Heat Equation with ode15

Tags: matlab, ode, temperature, pde

I am trying to solve the 2D heat equation and I am solving with ode15, I was directed that the dT/dt equation will have to be adjusted. Would it be possible to get some guidance on how I should go about it?

I've followed this example from Matlab: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59916-simple-heat-equation-solver?s_tid=srchtitle

How could the

```
du = alpha/dx^2*(u(1:end-2,2:end-1)-2*u(2:end-1,2:end-1)+u(2:end-1,3:end)...
    + u(2:end-1,1:end-2)-2*u(2:end-1,2:end-1)+u(3:end,2:end-1));

du = du(:);
```

part of the getRHS function from the example be changed to limit the temperature it rises up to?

Answer (score 0):

just add it before the ode as a threshold `thr` for `u0`, for example:

```
thr=0.5; % just some # I picked, 
u0(u0>thr)=thr;
```

Comment: Hi, ive tried the code and it seems to only print out the restricting temperature for me? Sorry...

Comment: play with the threshold value. use for example `inf`. this should do nothing. if that's not the case then you didnt implement it the way I suggested ...

Comment: Hi, I have realised that I forgot the ";" on the code that I typed. However, it still was not working. I have also tried to simply just copy paste your suggested code and here is the attempt: https://imgur.com/a/ok66z99

Comment: you do understand that in this example, the flow of heat will only decrease as function of time? so when you cap the temperature at t=0, (which in the example in the link it's actually `u0(u0>thr)=thr;` outside of the getRHS function)  it will be capped but then only decrease afterwards. I edited my answer.